# Using ModelFormMixin (base class of CreatePostView) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to pass the form to my createview  but facing improperly configured file error with following suggestion "Using ModelFormMixin (base class of CreatePostView) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited".

Any suggestion on how to tackle this problem??

```
  class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
        login_url='/login/'
        redirect_field_name='blog/post_list.html'
        from_class=PostForm
        model=Post

#Post Form is name of modelform
```

Comment: Use get and post function or add fields, Go through the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview to know more on generic views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo: `from_class` instead of `form_class`.